# Free tools to check compliance with MISRA C?

Tags: c, standards, misra

Are there any open-source or free tools out there, that check the [MISRA C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MISRA_C) compliance?

Answer (score 16):

Cppcheck (free and open source) has an official addon allowing to check MISRA-C 2012 rules.

The way to do so:

1. cppcheck --dump file.c
2. python misra.py file.c.dump

You can simply find misra.py in your Cppcheck installation or here: https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck/blob/master/addons/misra.py

Comment: Unfortunately, Cppcheck needs MISRA rules for this addon to work. These rules are not free and are not provided with Cppcheck.

Comment: Cppcheck does not need MISRA rules for this addon to work: if MISRA rules are providen users get full rules' message when an issue is found, otherwise users get only MISRA rules' id.

Answer (score 8):

Relatively speaking, PC-Lint is *virtually* free when compared to full-blown static analysis tools with MISRA compliance checks.  Furthermore, I have found that PC-Lint does a better job of reporting than those expensive (i.e. >$20,000) tools.

Comment: PC-Lint supports MISRA C and C++ compliance checking: http://www.gimpel.com/html/misra.htm

Comment: my bad. Comment deleted (and +1 to you)

Comment: Detail: "PC-Lint is virtually free" --> Found quote: "PC-lint - One Workstation License (non-floating) 389.00"